How to start a docker container on a remote pc thorugh cpp code using ssh?
I have two machines:

A: Weak machine that is only there for control
B: Strong machine without direct access

In my C++ Code on A I want to be able to run and stop different docker compose files on B. I dont need the print of these Containers on A and I also dont want them to block my command on A.
So a naive approach could be:
        std::string ssh_command = "ssh user@198.126.0.0 'docker compose -f /home/user/analysis.yml up system'";
        int result = std::system(ssh_command.c_str());
        if (result != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error executing SSH command: " << ssh_command << std::endl;
        }

But with this way I will receive alle the print in my terminal in A and also my code will not continue. What is an elegant way to do that? Since in the future I might launch also different stuff than dockers, I prefere using ssh.

I am not convinced that C++ is the right tool for the job compared to something like Ansible or a bash script.

How weak is A? Are multiple SSH connections going to bring things to a halt?

@sweenish the cpp code has also other purposes and is huge.
yes it would not be preferable to keep the connections. Isn’t there a solution where you just launch the container via ssh and than close the connection?

Like Ansible or a bash script? It sounds like to you need to [edit] your question with more context. Because everything you currently describe makes it sound like C++ is not the right tool for the job.
